# Redirect URL " domain .com/test " to Map url from IIS Server

Tags: iis, web-config, aruba

I need redirect [www.cisles.it/ita/lage](http://www.cisles.it/ita/lage) to

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Autoservice+Cisles/@46.563284,11.733379,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x43b0fc553eca94a3!8m2!3d46.5632844!4d11.7333793?hl=it-IT from web.config "IIS" - aruba hosting

```
Any suggestion?
```

Comment: What do you mean `from web.config "IIS" - aruba hosting` ? IIS has an url rewrite module to redirect url to another one. You can use it and configure a redirect rule.

Comment: `<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="ita/lage" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=" www.cisles.it" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Autoservice+Cisles/@46.563284,11.733379,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x43b0fc553eca94a3!8m2!3d46.5632844!4d11.7333793?hl=it-IT" />
                </rule>`